# How to get data from two SQL tables into .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Previously, I asked a question about getting data from two tables where I take one row in a table and join it with several rows in another table.  Here's the link to that discussion: [SQL Select data from two tables (one row -> multiple rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399496/sql-select-data-from-two-tables-one-row-multiple-rows)

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    customer.fName, customer.lName, phone.phoneNumber 
FROM 
    Customers customer 
        INNER JOIN phoneNumbers phone ON 
            customer.customerId = phone.customerId
```

What I would like to know now is: what is the best way to get this data organized in .net?

Let's suppose I have a C# class as following:

```
public class CustomerDetails
{
    int customerId;
    string fname;
    string lName;
    List<string> phoneNumbers;
}
```

For the sake of discussion, let's suppose that the above SQL query returns the following result:

fname, lname, phoneNumber
"John", "Smith", "111-111"
"Jane", "Doe", "222-1111"
"Jane", "Doe", "222-2222"

At a glance, I see that I have two customers; one has one phone number and the other has two phone numbers.  How can I write code to efficiently parse this in C#?

Comment: Are you executing by ADO or Linq?

Comment: How doe you know that Jane Doe and Jane Doe are not 2 separate people?

Comment: I know that Jane Doe and Jane Doe are the same person because this is a contrived example :-).  My real data is more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use LINQ to create a instance of the CustomerDetails class.

Let me know if you would like an example.

**Example 1:**

```
List<CustomerDetails> customers = db.Customers.Select(c => new CustomerDetails(){
                                                                  customerId = c.customerID,
                                                                  fname = c.fName,
                                                                  lName = c.lName,
                                                                  phoneNumbers = (from p in db.PhoneNumbers where p.customerID == c.customerID select p.phoneNumber1).ToList<String>()});
```

**Example 2:**

```
List<CustomerDetails> custs = (from c in db.Customers
                         select new CustomerDetails()
                         {
                             customerId = c.customerID,
                             fname = c.fName,
                             lName = c.lName,
                             phoneNumbers = (from p in db.PhoneNumbers where p.customerID == c.customerID select p.phoneNumber1).ToList<String>()
                         }).ToList<CustomerDetails>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are looking for ORM object-relational mapping. In .NET I can recommend IBatis.net or LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

I assume that the records are sorted by name in the SQL query's results and that you also select the customerID. Appending `"ORDER BY customer.fName, customer.lName"` to your original query will do the trick.

I'll assume that you get your result in a DataReader, so you can do the following:

```
// Lets start by declaring a collection for our records
List<CustomerDetails> myRecords = new List<CustomerDetails>();

// Iterate all records from the results and fill our collection
while (yourReader.Read())
{
    int customerID = int.Parse(yourReader["customerID"]);
    int nrRecords = myRecords.Count;

    if (nrRecords > 0 && myRecords[nrRecords - 1].customerId == customerID)
    {
        myRecords[nrRecords - 1].phoneNumbers.Add(yourReader["phoneNumber"]);
    }
    else
    {
        CustomerDetails newCustomerDetails = new CustomerDetails();
        newCustomerDetails.customerId = customerID;
        newCustomerDetails.fName = yourReader["fName"];
        newCustomerDetails.lName = yourReader["lName"];

        List<string> phoneNumberList = new List<string>();
        phoneNumberList.Add(yourReader["phoneNumber"]);
        newCustomerDetails.phoneNumbers = phoneNumberList;

        myRecords.Add(newCustomerDetails);
    }
}
```

P.S. If ordering the list is not an option, then you can't just check the latest added records customerid - instead you'll need to iterate through the myRecords list and search for the existance of it. This can be done in many ways including with myRecords.Contains() or with a foreach.

**Solution 2:**

 Do the telephone number grouping directly from SQL. Create a function for selecting a comma separated string with all the telephone numbers of a particular customer:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCommaSeparatedPhoneNumbers]
(
    @customerID int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @output varchar(max)
    select @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + phoneNumbers
    from phoneNumbers 
    where customerId = @customerID

    return @output
END
GO
```

Then you can nicely select the list of all customer you want:

```
SELECT customerId, dbo.GetCommaSeparatedPhoneNumbers(customerId)
FROM Customers 
GROUP BY customerId
```

This will return:

```
"John", "Smith", "111-111"
"Jane", "Doe", "222-1111,222-2222"
```

Now it's all a question of parsing the results with a foreach or while loop, but no checking for existance is needed. Just split the string at ',' and insert the values into the List. If there is a chance, that there will be no phone numbers for some customers, then you can filter that field for null.

PS. Will not work if there is a comma as pointed out by [BQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4632/bq) in his comment.

Comment: -1. This answer assumes that a phone number doesn't contain a comma. Commas are commonly used to indicate a 2-second pause before the extension number is dialed. Additionally, there's no reason to combine the records in the database to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the result, for each row check if it is in your list of costumers, if not, add a new one, if yes, add the phone number to the existing one.

Of course, you shouldn't parse the string use appropiate classes to access the database, like ado.net.

Comment: I've actually written some code to iterate, but it seems bloated and clunky.  I was hoping there might be a more efficient and clean way.